# No me reconoce la dirección de mi icono

Tags: angular

¿Por qué no me quiere agarrarar mi icono `.png` 32x32 en `angular-cli.json`?

Cambio la dirección en `index.html` pero nada; el `index` y el icono `.png` están en la misma dirección.

Comment: Podrías poner tu código?  Así podre ayudarte. También te invito a leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png" />
```

**Angular-cli.json:**

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.png" 
],
```

Una vez echo esto, recuerda:

> Que hay un caché en tu navegador, por lo tanto fuerza a que esta se
>   limpie. Hazlo con estas teclas, dependiendo del navegador: **Internet
>   Explorer:** `Ctrl + R` ; **Chrome:** `Ctrl + F5, or Shift + F5, o Ctrl
>   + R` ; **Firefox:** `Ctrl + Shift + R`
>
> **Otra alternativa** es teniendo la consola de desarrollador abierta, Click derecho sobre el icono de recargar "Vaciar cache y volver a cargar de manera forzosa"